# Proof of property of spanning trees

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation, trees

I am looking at a proof of the following property: "If graph T had order n, T is a tree if and only if it contains no cycles, and has n-1 edges."

The proof of <= is as follows:
Suppose T is a graph with n vertices, n-1 edges and no cycles.
Since there are no cycles, there exists no more than one path between any two vertices.
Now if T is disconnected, suppose it is made up of k connected subgraphs, k>1, none of which contains a cycle.
Therefore, T is made up of k components, each of which is a tree.
But a tree with m vertices has m-1 edges, so for k disconnected trees with a total of n vertices, the total number of edges is n-k.
Hence, k=1, which is a contradiction.
Therefore, T must be connected, and since it contains no cycles it is a tree.

Now I understand the proof except for the part which states that k=1. I do not see a reason for k to have to equal 1. Why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We obtain $k=1$ because we assumed that $T$ has $n-1$ edges and showed that $T$ has $n-k$ edges.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thanks so much.

Comment: You're welcome!